# I am trying to set properties inside a class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set properties in this class:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    public Age Age { get; set; }
    public Household Household { get; set; }
    public MaritalStatus MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public Kids Kids { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }    
}
```

Here I am trying to set the Ids:

```
var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser()
{
   Id = user.Id,
   Name = new Name() { Id = user.Id },
   Age = new Age() { Id = user.Id },
   Address = new Address() { Id = user.Id },
   Household = new Household() { Id = user.Id },
};
```

Comment: can you explain more about your issue? Is this when trying to create new ApplicationUser with HTTP post? What is the error your are having?  I am not sure about your object model too. Why to you have IDs for Name and Age classes? What are the other properties for name and age?

Comment: I want to add GenderId = some value say '1' in that applicationUser class but I can't access Gender. Id and same for status I can't access that status.Id class

Comment: can you paste the content of gender and status classes?

Comment: public class Gender
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this is the error i get